# Which of these 3 mutation rates is the best in terms of performance?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, hyper-parameters, genetic-programming, genetic-operators, mutation-operators

I am need some comments since I am conducting experiments with `3` different `mutation rates` and hesitate to choose the best one.

I am working on a minimization problem where the `optimal value is 1.039`. Using `3` different mutation rates, I am able to to get optimal value. However, I am not sure which curve (shown in Fig.) is the best representation of a good mutation operator.

**Output:**

[image]

**Which curve is the best representation of a mutation operator?** I am in the process of testing other hyperparameters (number of generations, sample size) to see results.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to compare the fitness with the number of iterations/generations (rather than time in seconds)? The time it takes may depend also on your CPU workload, etc.

Comment: @nbro I already did a comparison based on the fitness with the number of iterations. Besides, I am comparing multiple sample sizes to see the execution time it takes to process candidates solution.

Comment: How do the graphs looks when you run seven times with the *same* mutation rate?